How to log in to Copilot in VSCode - authentication failed
I've had Copilot working in VSCode but it stopped working when I tried out Google Code Assist.
I removed all extensions. Then installed GitHub Copilot, GitHub Copilot Chat, GitHub Actions but all attempts to go through authentication have failed.
Is the next step to uninstall VSCode and reinstall? If so, what's the best way of doing that?
UPDATE: I tried cleaning up by putting application into trash and deleting all extensions using the codes - Mac OS.
rm
 -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code
rm
 -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist
rm
 -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode
rm
 -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/
rm
 -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState
rm
 -rf ~/.vscode

Just installed with Copilot, Copilot Chat, Python, Jupyter but although I get a prompt pressing return doesn't submit.
Moreover if I try command prompt to sign in, I have this error.


What OS are you using?

Mac Os. Sonoma.

I've managed to clean reinstall but same problems with copilot. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/119670

I'd suggest you put as much info into what you've already tried into your question. It'll help more people identify the problem more easily. Think information like reinstalling, what your subscription to Copilot is like, which plugins you've installed, any error messages you're getting etc.
Also FYI double-posting isn't received well. Avoid it if possible
